# Django templating language doesn't display anything

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my `views.py`:

```
questions = list(Question.objects.all())
for question in questions:
    print(question.content)
return render_to_response('questions.html', questions)
```

Which prints:

```
How much is 2 + 2?
What's the tallest mountain on Earth?
```

So the `questions` list is not empty.

`questions.html` is:

```
<head></head>

<body>
These are the questions!!!

  <ul>
    {% for question in questions %}
    <li><p>{{ question.content }}</p></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

</body>
```

The problem is that when I access `questions.html` in the browser, the questions' content is not displayed.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template doesn't know about the variable name you used when you passed the context. Try:

```
return render_to_response('questions.html', {'questions': questions})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return render_to_response('questions.html', {'questions': questions})
```

Your template is expecting an object( context) with questions list in it.